# C : how to ensure both conditions have to be met for print

Tags: c

This is an assignment for my C introduction web class.

Source code (in progress):

```
#include <stdio.h>
    
    int main ()
    {
        int age, output;
        char sex, test;
        
        printf("Oletko mies vai nainen (m/n)? ");
            scanf("%c", &sex); 
        
        
            
        printf("Anna ikäsi: ");
            scanf("%d", &age);
        
        if (sex == 'm' && age <= 55);
        {
            printf("Olet mies parhaassa iässä!");
        }
        
         if (age >= 56 && sex == 'm');
        
        {
            printf("Olet viisas mies!");
        }
        
        
    }
```

result:

```
Oletko mies vai nainen (m/n)? m
Anna ikäsi: 23
Olet mies parhaassa iässä!Olet viisas mies!
```

right, so, this seems to print both results if the answer to "sex" is `m`, how do I ensure *both* conditions have to be met? or can this even be achieved?

## edit3:

thank you for your extremely fast answers! will mark as solved when the site will allow me to.

Comment: Remove the `;`s from after your `if` conditions.  Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: You should go for `else if` instead of two `if` in such cases. Else your conditions are correct, it's just the `;` typo as said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a semi color extra in every if condition

```
if (sex == 'm' && age <= 55);
{
    printf("Olet mies parhaassa iässä!");
}
if (age >= 56 && sex == 'm');
{
    printf("Olet viisas mies!");
}
```

so your messages will be printed no matter what you give as input

Do remove those ; and use an if else condition instead:

```
if (sex == 'm' && age <= 55)
{
    printf("Olet mies parhaassa iässä!");
}
else if (age >= 56 && sex == 'm')
{
    printf("Olet viisas mies!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`if (sex == 'm' && age <= 55);`
The `;` after `if()` makes a blank statement for `if()`. Thus the statement `printf()` is not inside `if()`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove ; from the if statements. Rest is fine.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify the issue, if after an `if` you don't use brackets, then only one line of code will be inside its block. And as lines end with `;`, by just placing a `;` you are placing an empty line there. Like this:

```
if (condition)
    ;
next line....
```

Brackets are optional for single line if blocks, but mandatory if there are more lines. For example:

```
if (condition)
    something;
else if (condition2)
{
   something_else;
}
else if (condition3)
{
   something_else;
   something_else;
}
```

Besides this, you can avoid checking for `'m'` twice by doing this:

```
if (sex == 'm')
{
    if (age <= 55)
    {
        printf("Olet mies parhaassa iässä!");
    }
    else if (age >= 56)
    {
        printf("Olet viisas mies!");
    }
}
```